# VS2015 Excel Web AddIn crashes Excel 2016

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, office365, excel-2016

I have created a new Excel web addin in Visual Studio 2015.

Ran the default project without changes in Excel 2016.

When I clicked on "Show taskpane" in Excel's ribbon, Excel crashes.

I've tried repairing office and visual studio, followed by reinstalling them completely, but the problem still persists.

Is this a known issue? What else can I try, shy of resetting or reformatting windows?

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Update 3
- Office Developer Tools 14.0.23928
- 64-bit Windows 10 pro, no new window updates
- 32-bit Excel 2016 (Pro Plus), updated/reinstalled today,

  - all COM addins/addins disabled

This is what I see when I click on the `Show Taskpane` ribbon button:
[image: Crash screen]

The task pane appears, but after a split second, excel crashes

Here's my event log:

```
Faulting application name: excel.exe, version: 16.0.7070.2033, time stamp: 0x57964b42
Faulting module name: excel.exe, version: 16.0.7070.2033, time stamp: 0x57964b42
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00550741
Faulting process id: 0x2f48
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1e8b065284199
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excel.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excel.exe
Report Id: 933c7866-674b-42c0-a5f4-3c93b6c26525
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've commented out some code, and did a line-by-line step-through, and when I attempt to step over/into `ctx.sync()`, it crashes

[image]

I've run OffCAT, and it's saying there're no issues detected

[image]

Comment: Does the bug occurs when VisualStudio debugger is not attached?

Comment: yup. Even with "start without debugging", Excel still crashes. Btw, when debugging, I've also turned on all options in the exceptions settings window  "Break when thrown" (ie js runtime, webkit runtime, mda, c++), but the debugger never breaks. Excel just crashes immediately

Comment: what happens if you change some values in the context before trying to sync ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed my problem.
These were the steps I took to get it to work again:

1. Uninstalled visual studio using Visual Studio Uninstaller ([Github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller))
2. Uninstalled Office 2016
3. Deleted Microsoft\office folders from %appdata% and %localappdata%
4. Reinstalled Visual studio 2015
5. Reinstalled Office developer tools ([Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx))
6. Reinstalled Office 2016

Since my previous attempt to uninstall/reinstall office and visual studio was still not working, I thought it had to be caused by somethings left behind.

So this time round, I made sure to wipe everything related that I could think of. I still do not know what caused it to crash, but at least it's working now.

Deleting stuff in appdata and localappdata was a last resort, and not a decision taken lightly. Had it not worked, my next attempt would've been a full windows reset.